# Parse shortcodes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to parse shortcodes in a string, which will return their ids and values in an array of objects like the following:

```
var str = 'First shortcode is [fraction num="1" denom="2"] and the second is [square-root content="456"] which we will pass into a function which will return these IDs and all their values in an array of objects like below';
var obj = parseShortcodes(str);

// obj now equals:

[
 {
  id: 'fraction',
  num: 1,
  denom: 2
 },
 {
  id: 'square-root',
  content: 456
 }
]
```

Comment: the output is invalid object, perhaps, you meant array?

Comment: Yes thank you I've amended the question.

Answer (score 4):

Complex solution:

```js
var parseShortcodes = function(str){
    var regex = /\[\S+(?:\s+[^="]+="[^"\]\s]+")+\]/g,
 m, obj, result = [];
  
 while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
     if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
  regex.lastIndex++;
     }
     m = m[0].slice(1, -1).split(/\s+/);
     result.push(m.reduce(function(r, s){ 
         var pair = s.split('=');
  r[pair[0]] = +pair[1].slice(1,-1);
  return r;
     }, {id: m.shift()}));  
 }
 
 return result;
};

var str = `First shortcode is [fraction num="1" denom="2"] and the second is [square-root content="456"] which we will pass into a function which will return these IDs and all their values in an object like below'`;

console.log(parseShortcodes(str));
```

Comment: It does indeed work thank you! Going to work on this to see what can be done but thank you.

Comment: @tjcafferkey, you're welcome