# How can I create a shortcode in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I create a shortcut in JavaScript such as Wordpress?

For example, when I put this code inside a certain text

```
[youtube src="wKrf2lYp9NU" autoplay='true'/]
```

It will be replaced by YouTube video with autoplay

Thanks

Comment: `[youtube src="wKrf2lYp9NU" autoplay='true'/]` doesn't look like JavaScript. Which language is it?

Comment: Please see this https://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/04/create-a-YouTube-Shortcode-in-Blogger.html  It uses the same principle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse shortcodes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963590/parse-shortcodes-in-javascript)

Comment: @zcserei The two questions are different, I want to convert the shortcode into a video

Comment: @jimi-del once you parsed the shortcode, you can grab that data and turn it into a video embed, for a basic solution you can just turn the YouTube embed code into a string literal and embed the parsed values

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about shortcuts, but this is the code for the DOM

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';
video.autoplay = true;
```